# Pytesseract - OCR on image with colored text

Tags: python-3.x, macos, ocr, python-tesseract

im trying to use Pytesseract to get some text in an image. However, the text is an orange color and the background has both black and white. I have tried several options but ultimately I'm unable to read the text using Pytesseract. Below is a sample of the image:
[image]

Here is the code I have arrived at:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image,ImageOps
import numpy as np

img = Image.open("OCR.png").convert("L")
img = ImageOps.invert(img)
# img.show()
threshold = 240
table = []
pixelArray = img.load()
for y in range(img.size[1]):  # binaryzate it
    List = []
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        if pixelArray[x,y] < threshold:
            List.append(0)
        else:
            List.append(255)
    table.append(List)

img = Image.fromarray(np.array(table, dtype="uint8")) # load the image from array.
# img.show()

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

The code above results in an all black image. Text becomes black too